# Run PHP everywhere from command line on windows 7

Tags: php, cmd, phpunit, wamp

I'm using Yii and a WampServer 2.4 64bit.
I installed PEAR and PHPUnit manually.

I can only run the commands PHP, PEAR or PHPUnit  in the install folder:

```
E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12
```

But I want to execute the commands PHP and PHPUnit from here:

```
E:\wamp\www\repo\project\protected\tests
```

So I added the path to my `php.exe` to my PATH environment variable like this:

```
;E:\wamp\www\bin\php\php5.4.12
```

But I can't call `php -v` on `E:\wamp\www\repo\project\protected\tests` without the error message, that the command is unknown.

I followed a lot of tutorials how to add php or PHPUnit to my environment variable PATH but nothing is working.

So I realy realy hope,someone can explain me where my mistake is.

Comment: Did you open a new terminal after editing the PATH?

Comment: yes I did. but it always says "command not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably added a "www" that is not needed in your PATH variable

`;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12`

seems the correct version to me.

Comment: omfg THANK YOU. I never see this. I changed it and it works quite fine. Thanks a lot !